# Why can't I change ```font-feature-settings``` directly with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, opentype

I want to make a simple web page to test OpenType features.

What I want: I simply enter some text and the feature I want to use in inputboxes, and click a button to change the content and style of a `div`.

However I found that the `font-feature-settings` wouldn't change as I expect. For example,

```html
<html>

<body>
  <input id="feature" /><input type="button" value="Change Feature" onclick="
    alert(document.getElementById('feature').value);
    document.getElementById('display').style.fontFeatureSettings=document.getElementById('feature').value;
    alert(document.getElementById('display').style.fontFeatureSettings);" />
  <div id="display" style="font-size:72;">Some text</div>
</body>

</html>
```

In my Chrome, the first message box shows what I inputed, yet the second message box is always empty.

I end up defining a lot of CSS classes and changing them with javascript. It works now, but it doesn't meet my need, for I have to predefine a lot of features and thus have difficulty in extending it for future use.

Comment: What did you type into the input field? Some of the feature settings have to be quoted, e.g. `"smcp"`. If you just type `smcp` it won't work.

Comment: Thank you, it solved my problem. I just typed `liga`, rather than `"liga"`.

Comment: I can also strongly recomment not inlining JS and styles. Keep them in their own files, so that linting (i.e. "correctness checking") can run on them and tell you this in your code editor immediately. And instead of using JS to set `style` values, add a class that turns on (or off) the feature(s) you need) through `element.classList,add()`, which you defined separately in your CSS file(s). (which, of course, also means using `addEventListener` in your JS, not `onclick` in your HTML. Just remember to load your JS with `<script src="..." async defer></script>`)